# Pinning tacks to a board

Tags: graph-theory

You are pinning tacks to a board and tying lines between them. If two tacks are tied to the same number of tacks, then there is no tack that both tacks are tied to. Furthermore, all tacks are tied to themselves. Prove that there must exist a tack which is tied onto only one other tack.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the loops mean that the neighborhood of a vertex includes the vertex, so no vertex is adjacent to a vertex of the same degree. With this understanding, I’ll eliminate the loops from the graph, so that the degree of a vertex is the number of *other* vertices to which it’s adjacent.

HINT: Let $v_0$ be a vertex of maximal degree, say $d$, and let $v_1,\ldots,v_d$ be the vertices adjacent to $v_0$. Being adjacent to $v_0$, they must all have degree different from $d$, and all of them are connected to $v_0$, so ... ?

Comment: @Frazjier: No induction is needed. Just observe that the degrees of $v_1,\ldots,v_d$ are all $\le d$ (since $d$ is maximal), different from $d$ (because the vertices are adjacent to $v_0$), and different from one another (for the same reason). Since they must be non-negative integers, the only possibility is that they are the $d$ integers $0,1,\ldots,d-1$.